# HoloEverywhere error in first line or not working VCS to Git connection

Tags: git, android-holo-everywhere

I want to use the HoloEveryWhere theme and was reading introduction guide, but I have problems with the first line. I can't clone it because "Clone failed: Failed to start Git process" or "Repository test has failed", but I don't know what is wrong.

Introductions from official page: [HoloEverywhere](https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere/wiki/Import-in-IDE)

> #### Android Studio / IntelliJ IDEA
>
> - Checkout from Version Control - Git
> - Typo in Repository URL: `https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere.git`
> - Press 'Clone', wait until repository checkout
> - If you use Android Studio, then just click 'Yes' on the proposal to open a project. Otherwise in IDEA press Import project and specify path to downloaded repo, choose gradle model and press next.
> - Mark checkbox "Use auto-import" and click finish.
> - Kiss a Google and Android devs team!
> - Read [this basic migration guide](https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere/wiki/Basic-migration-on-HoloEverywhere)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I have the same problem 5 minutes ago.
You need to download and install git from http://git-scm.com/downloads

Then you need to track the git.exe on AndroidStudio:

Settings > Project Settings > Version Control > VCSs > Git
Path to Git executeable : D:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd\git.exe